# What is the JToolBar equivalent of frame.setJMenuBar(ie.createMenuBar());?

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jtoolbar

I can't find it anywhere at all, I've tried all obvious names.

I have it working for the ContentPane and the JMenuBar.

This is what I tried last:

```
ImageEditor ie = new ImageEditor();     
    frame.setJMenuBar(ie.createMenuBar());
    frame.setContentPane(ie.createContentPane());
    frame.setJToolBar(ie.createToolBar());
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't one.  Traditionally the toolbar is added to the outside positions of a container that is using a `BorderLayout`...

```
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // This is actually the default layout anyway
frame.setJMenuBar(ie.createMenuBar());
frame.getContentPane().add(ie.createContentPane());
frame.getContentPane().add(ie.createToolBar(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

I say traditionally, as the last time I used a floating toolbar, it would throw an exception if you tried to add it back to a container that did not use a `BorderLayout`, this may have being fixed in more recent releases

Take a look at [How to use ToolBars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) for more details